# Can I use OnItemClickListener for ListView with OnClickListener for items?

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

Is it possible to use OnItemClickListener for ListView and OnClickListener for their items together? This is not nesessary, but in my case it more comfortable to separate functionality beetween Adapter (onClick) and Activity (onItemClick). And when I try to use these listeners together, only OnClickListener works.

All what I do is:

```
public class ProfilePassengersListActivity extends ConnectActivity
{
    protected ListView lv;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.another_passengers_list_screen);
        anotherPassengersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.anotherPassengersListListViewPassengers);
        lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(openInfoTraveler);
    }
    private android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener openInfoTraveler = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) 
          {
              Log.i(LOGTAG, "in onclick");
          }
    };
}
```

And at adapter:

```
public class ProfilePassengersListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
...
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final String currObj = list.get(position);
        if(convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_delete_confirmation) == null)
        {
            RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(ctx);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_delete_confirmation, null);
            convertView.setTag("main");
            container.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, convertView.getHeight()));
            container.addView(convertView);
            container.addView(child);
            convertView = container;
        }
        if(!preparedToDelete.contains(list.get(position)))
        {
            convertView.findViewWithTag("main").setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_delete_confirmation).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.findViewWithTag("main").setVisibility(View.GONE);
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_delete_confirmation).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Log.i("wtf", "prepared to delete: " + currObj);
        }
        final View itemView = convertView;
        /*convertView.setFocusable(false);
        convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        convertView.setClickable(true);*/
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "onClick");
            }
        });
        return convertView;
}
```

Comment: POST YOUR CODE HERE...

Comment: Why would you want too? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes it is possible to enable both the listeners. But the issue is how are you enabling both of them. That's why post some code. We will come to know why ur code is not working

Comment: You can write an OnClickListener method in your Adapter for your views. and You can also write onItemClickListener for your listView in Activity. I am using this frequently in my apps. If you show your code I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

`lv.setOnItemClickListener(openInfoTraveler);`

instead of this:

`lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(openInfoTraveler);`